# Возврат функции в C++ наподобие замыкания в Python

Tags: python, c++

В языке Python есть такая опция как замыкание:

```
def func():
    x = 5
    def inner():
        print(f'Переменная из замыкания: {x}')
    return inner
func()()
```

Функция-родитель обращается к дочерней функции, которая находится внутри родительской и возвращает её после обращения.

Слышал, что в C++ такое возможно с помощью лямбда-функций и более безопасно.

Не могли бы вы привести пример для новичков возврата функции(указателя на функцию) в C++?

Вопрос больше для расширения кругозора: в реальных задачах еще не было необходимости в использовании таких средств языка.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, в C/С++ напрямую невозможно. К тому же, замыкание не безопасно. Используйте классы/глобальные переменные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В C++11 это называется Lambda expressions: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

```
std::function<void()> func()
{
  int x=5;
  auto inner=[x](){ 
    std::cout<<"Переменная из замыкания: "<<x<<std::endl; 
  };
  return inner;
}
```

Или (если точка возврата у функции одна):

```
auto func()
{
  int x=5;
  auto inner=[x](){ 
    std::cout<<"Переменная из замыкания: "<<x<<std::endl; 
  };
  return inner;
}
```

Обращаю внимание, что возвращаемый объект не является указателем на функцию, и никак не может быть преобразован в С-й указатель на функцию. Это связано с тем, что в С указатели на функции - просто адреса кода функции в памяти, и не могут нести состояние, а функции python - объекты с состоянием.

Но из функции можно возвращать объект с перегруженным `operator ()`, который будет вести себя как функция при передаче его в другие шаблонные функции, например в качестве компаратора. Лямбда-выражение является таким объектом.

`std::function<...>` позволяет стирать конкретный тип возвращаемого объекта, ценой вызова виртуальной функции, при каждом вызове `operator ()`. Зато становится возможно forward-declaration (разнесение декларации и определения на .h и .cpp).

Comment: На англоязычном ресурсе нашёл схожий вопрос. Там достаточно большое обсуждение:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726768/function-returning-a-lambda-expression

Comment: А не могли вы пояснить строчку "Это связано с тем, что в С указатели на функции - просто адреса кода функции в памяти, и не могут нести состояние, а функции python - объекты с состоянием". Не очень понимаю что подразумевается под термином "состояние". Вас не затруднит немного пояснить.

Comment: @Bizzarro в питоне можно: `def func():...` `func.x=42`,  и результат вычисления функции (потенциально) может измениться.  В С++ так нельзя. (Все атрибуты функции - только в compile time.)